# Removing CH340g chip from Arduino Nano clone.. any issues?

Tags: arduino-nano, ch340

In trying to figure out how to solve another [problem with Arduino Nano clone using CH340 chip](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/nano-clone-not-working-over-usb-no-data-no-power-but-can-power-via-vin-schot), I was just now wondering, would there be any issues if I were to simply remove the CH340 chip? As it stands, I have the slight suspicion that the chip itself might be causing some problems with communicating using only the Tx Rx pins, could this be the case? More importantly, can I just remove the chip with no issues (other than the already lacking ability to use it as USB-Serial bridge)? In a working board, would removing the chip cause any other problems?

Comment: If you are not going to use the chip, can't you just ignore it?

Comment: @NickGammon, the reason is because I have a feeling it is actually defective and interfering with communication over the TxRx pins. See the linked question for a little background on that.

Answer (score 1):

No problem whatsoever as long as you aren't powering the board over USB. You may still be able to do that though depending on what role the CH has in managing the power.

Personally I think all CH chip should be removed from all boards. They are horrible chips and cause no end of problems.

I assume you have an FT232 adapter board (or similar) to then use for the programming of your Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the datasheet, I see no problem with removing it.

I'd suggest using a sharp knife and cut all the pins, one at a time, right where they come out of the black epoxy. Make sure you don't accidentally stab into the PCB. Remove the main body of the chip. After that, remove the legs still attached to the PCB, one by one, using a soldering iron.

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed a burned ch340 from a dysfunctional uno, and it didn't brought it back to life, I couldn't program it by other means, because reset remained shorted to ground. It might have other problems, but I still recommend digging more into the problem (eg. Check the diagram for your board)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with just removing 3 legs - Tx, Rx, and DTR. The rest don't anything.
The pins are rather far apart, you could heat them one at a time gently pry/lify up with tweezers too. Better than a knife I would think.